# Get text with quotes inside one tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse web page using BeautifulSoup.

Case 1:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def</div>
    <div class="c">123 456</div>
</div>
```

Case 2:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        "abc "
        "def"
    </div>
    <div class="c">123 456</div>
</div>
```

I want to get a text from class C using the code:

```
c = soup.find('div', class = 'b', text = 'abc def').next_sibling.text
```

In Case 1 it works well. But in Case 2 it doesn't work. For Case 2 I tried also:

```
c = soup.find('div', class = 'b', text = '"abc ""def"').next_sibling.text
```

In both cases

```
soup.find('div', class = 'b').text
```

gives me the same value:

```
abc def
```

What is the right way to work with Case 2?

**[EDIT #1]**

I need to do this way because there are several div with the same class:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def1</div>
    <div class="c">123</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def2</div>
    <div class="c">456</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        "abc "
        "def3"
    </div>
    <div class="c">789</div>
</div>
```

**[EDIT #2]**

I tried to save response.text to file and saw, that it looks like:

```
    <div class="b">abc <!-- -->def3</div>
```

But in Chrome it looks like:

```
    <div class="b">
        "abc "
        "def3"
    </div>
```

Also, I can't get text by re.compile if the text inside tag is like:

```
    <div class="b">abc m<sup>2</sup></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just match the class as `soup.find('div', class = 'b').next_sibling.text` and you look for the text of C? Apparently they all are of different classes, so it could be the fit.

Comment: I have several <div> with class B, that is why I need to look through the text inside the tag.

Comment: I assume you want to select C based on B otherwise you would just select C?

Comment: @QHarr I add EDIT in my question.

Comment: @Room'on : I have updated one answer.please check if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find next element with tag name and then print the value.
You can use `re` module to search text.
Here you have two examples.

**Example 1:**

```
import bs4
htmldoc='''<html><div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        "abc "
        "def"
    </div>
    <div class="c">123 456</div>
</div></html>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmldoc, 'html.parser')
c = soup.find('div', class_='b').findNext('div').contents[0]
print(c)
```

output:

`123 456`

**Example 2:**

```
import bs4
import re

htmldoc='''<html><div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        "abc "
        "def"
    </div>
    <div class="c">123 456</div>
</div></html>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmldoc, 'html.parser')

d = soup.find('div', text=re.compile('def')).findNext('div').contents[0]
print(d)
```

output:

```
123 456
```

**Example 3:**

```
import bs4

htmldoc='''<html><div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def1</div>
    <div class="c">123</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def2</div>
    <div class="c">456</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        "abc "
        "def3"
    </div>
    <div class="c">789</div>
</div></html>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmldoc, 'html.parser')

c = soup.find_all('div', class_='b')
for d in c:
   text=d.findNext('div').contents[0]
   print(text)
```

Output:

```
123
456
789
```

Example 4:

```
import bs4

htmldoc='''<html><div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def1</div>
    <div class="c">123</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def2</div>
    <div class="c">456</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        "abc "
        "def3"
    </div>
    <div class="c">789</div>
</div></html>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmldoc, 'html.parser')
d=soup.find(lambda tag:tag.name=="div" and "abc " in tag.text and  "def3" in tag.text).findNext('div').findNext('div').contents[0]

print(d)
```

output:

```
789
```

**Example 5:**

```
import bs4

htmldoc='''<html><div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def1</div>
    <div class="c">123</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def2</div>
    <div class="c">456</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        "abc "
        "def3"
    </div>
    <div class="c">789</div>
</div></html>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmldoc, 'html.parser')

c = soup.find_all('div', class_='b')
for d in c:
   if (('abc ' in d.text) and ('def3' in d.text)):
     textc=d.findNext('div').contents[0]
     print(textc)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In your Example 2, why can't I use `text='abc def'` instead of `text=re.compile('def')`?

Comment: @Room'on: because it is regular expression so you should use the unique text to search. in Example 3  you can use `text=re.compile('abc')` if you see `abc` is common to all b tag text.

Comment: I just need to get `abc def3` (789) in your Example 3. It is not always in 3rd place. How can I get it?

Comment: @Room'on : you can use partial text like : `d = soup.find('div', text=re.compile('def3')).findNext('div').contents[0]
print(d)`

Comment: What if I have both `abc def3` and `qwe def3`? My question is how to work with text inside one tag, separated in several lines with double quotes.

Comment: Is there a more simple way? Why `soup.find('div', class_ = 'b').text' is 'abc def3`, but I can't use it exactly?

Comment: try example 5 then.

Comment: I have updated my question with EDIT 2. I saw that what I see in Chrome is not the same I see in saved response.text...